# Logstash jdbc plugin issue

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-jdbc

I am using logstash jdbc plugin to transfer data from db to elasticsearch.
When picking data from db the column names are in lowercase.
But I need the column names to be changed to uppercase and the values to be inserted in the already created index with fields having uppercase.

I tried using

```
filter{
   mutate {
     uppercase => [ "column1" , "column2" , "column3" ]
   }
}
```

I have already created an index in ES having COLUMN1 , COLUMN2 , COLUMN3.
 But when I run the logstash file its creating new fields column1, column2,column3 and not indexing any data in fields COLUMN1 ,COLUMN2 ,COLUMN3.

Comment: What the `mutate/uppercase` filter does is uppercasing the values of the fields named in the array, not the field names themselves.

Comment: It means the data stored under the field is changed to uppercase before inserting to elastic search ??

Comment: Yes, but not the field name itself

Comment: Is there any way to rename the field ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but have you seen the [lowercase_column_names](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-lowercase_column_names) parameter at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html? It defaults to true, meaning that logstash will lowercase the column names from the JDBC result set.